# Server presenting RSA key instead of ECDSA when someone tries to ssh

Tags: ssh, rhel

On Server B, I have ECDSA, RSA and ED25519 private and public keys available in `/etc/ssh/`.

When server A tried to `ssh` to Server B it received the RSA key fingerprint to authenticate and fails because in its `known_hosts` it has Server B's ECDSA key fingerprint not the RSA key's, and strict key checking is enabled.

I cant make changes to Server A, on Server B I can.
So how can I make Server B present ECDSA key to any server in this case Server A when they try to connect through SSH? Or in other words make ECDSA the default key identity for Server B instead of RSA?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on Server B that it can use ECDSA keys (in /etc/ssh/sshd_config should be uncommented) :

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

Comment: Yes, these lines are present in sshd_config and uncommented.